# Java if statement not working

Tags: java, if-statement

In my code I'm trying to make an if statement to have my final grades be equal to my theory and or practical if 1 or both of them are below 50%. If both are under 50%, the lowest one needs to equal the final grade. NOTE: I put a lot brackets in the code that i cannot get working if this helps.

Comment: What's not working? Please be explicit. And comments in code are a better option to highlight certain code.

Comment: if(theory < 50 ) {
            final_grade = theory;
           }
            else if (practical < 50)
            final_grade = practical;                                                                                          This part doesnt work how I thought it would.

Comment: Yes, that's already clear. You haven't said what the actual problem is though.

Comment: Please state explicitly and precisely how your observed result differs from the expected.

Comment: First, your calculations are off. You don't need to divide by 100 and then multiply by 100. That just produces the original result. Also dividing by 70 and then multiplying by 100 doesn't produce 70%, just multiply by 0.7 to do that. Same for dividing by 30 then multiplying by 100, just multiply by 0.3.

Second, what happens when theory and practical are both 50?

Comment: What are you Inputs?

Comment: when i run the program i want my final grade to equal theory or practical grade if 1 of them are lower than 50% but when i run it, it just gives the average like before the code

Comment: Because your print statements are keying off of the `grade_letter` but your "set the minimum" logic sets the `final_grade`...

Comment: @Azose Thanks for providing more and important information. Please use the edit link under the question to add the information in there so we have everything in one place. After you have done that, I shall be happy to vote for reopening the question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is the fact that if `theory < 50`, then it will evaluate the code in the block of the "if" statement and then leave that `if-else` block. If you want to check for both, you could say something like:

```
if (theory < 50 || practical < 50) {
   final_grade = Math.min(theory, practical);
}
```

Which would set `final_grade` to the smaller of the two grades. Even if one is greater than 50, it would not matter because the other grade would still be less than 50 and smaller than the other grade.